# Login as an admin to a firebase Realtime database through postman

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have these rules set for a firebase realtime database

```
{
  "rules": {
    "adminContent": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a user and can sign in
following this URL
[https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

```
{
    "email":"MY EMAIL",
    "password":"MYPASSWORD",
    "returnSecureToken":true
}
```

I get the idToken and all the data.
I input in Params: auth | "THE ID TOKEN RECEIVED"

I am still getting

```
{
    "error": "Permission denied"
}
```

I am guessing I am supposed to be registered as an admin or get some data as an admin.

I actually need this for a react project but I was testing things in Postman and I don't understand how this thing is working.

I have to keep these rules.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your security rule requires the user to be an admin:

```
auth.token.admin === true
```

But signing the user in does not automatically make then an admin, as that would be a pretty big security risk.

You'll need to run code in a trusted environment that marks the user as an admin. This `admin` value is known as a custom claim, so I recommend reading the documentation on [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) and specifically this section on [setting custom claims through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk).

After doing that, the next time you sign the user in, they'll have that `admin` claim and it will be passed along to the security rules.

Comment: I am sorry I am kind of new to this whole thing.  "You'll need to run code in a trusted environment that marks the user as an admin."  that means that I can't do that from Postman? What does a trusted environment mean? I have to create a Node server or my react app working on local machine is fine. Sorry for the dumb question. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you mark someone as an admin in Postman that'd be fine, but if anyone else can run the same in Postman - then what's stopping them from marking themselves as an administrator. That's why this code (which need administrative access to your Firebase project) needs to run in a trusted environment, which is a place where you can be certain that only you can run it, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hi, sorry again I have been reading through the documentation and I still don't get it. I know I am dumb cause every tutorial on the internet is skipping this step and I don't get it. How am I supposed to get this admin token in a React application? I was given an assignment and apparently, I am not able to solve this. I read that to make changes to the rules you can do it through firebase SDK. I can do that. But how do I get this admin token do I get it through the SDK and then put in my react that doesn't make much sense. How do I make API calls to the firebase REST API.